# How to get name of wifi-network out of android using android API?

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I thought that I should use NetworkInterface::getDisplayName. I got some name, but this name is different that this name which I can see, when I choosing to which network I want to connect.

Comment: Does anyone know which permissions are needed to do this?

Comment: android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`android.net.wifi.WifiInfo.getSSID`?

---

```
WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
String name = wifiInfo.getSSID();
```

Comment: For Xamarin C#: `Android.Net.Wifi.WifiInfo.SSID`

Comment: I have added the question asker's answer into your answer. I hope that is ok @Loxley.

Comment: WifiManager is not known in xamarin, do I need to add some packaqe ? And what is `context` ?

Answer (score 25):

```
public String getWifiName(Context context) {
    WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if (manager.isWifiEnabled()) {
       WifiInfo wifiInfo = manager.getConnectionInfo();
       if (wifiInfo != null) {
          DetailedState state = WifiInfo.getDetailedStateOf(wifiInfo.getSupplicantState());
          if (state == DetailedState.CONNECTED || state == DetailedState.OBTAINING_IPADDR) {
              return wifiInfo.getSSID();
          }
       }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What is `WifiManager` ? How do I get xamarin to know this ?

Answer (score 19):

This (mix and match of various answers from Marakana and others) will simultaneously get everything you want to extract from:

1. all wifi routers in range
2. connected wifi router
3. all stored wifi networks (on your device)

   ```
   public String getCurrentSsid(Context context) {

     String ssid = null;
     ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
     NetworkInfo networkInfo = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
     if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
       final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
       final WifiInfo connectionInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
       if (connectionInfo != null && !(connectionInfo.getSSID().equals(""))) {
           //if (connectionInfo != null && !StringUtil.isBlank(connectionInfo.getSSID())) {
         ssid = connectionInfo.getSSID();
       }
    // Get WiFi status MARAKANA
       WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
       String textStatus = "";
       textStatus += "\n\nWiFi Status: " + info.toString();
       String BSSID = info.getBSSID();
       String MAC = info.getMacAddress();

       List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
       ScanResult bestSignal = null;
       int count = 1;
       String etWifiList = "";
       for (ScanResult result : results) {
           etWifiList += count++ + ". " + result.SSID + " : " + result.level + "\n" +
                   result.BSSID + "\n" + result.capabilities +"\n" +
                   "\n=======================\n";
       }
       Log.v(TAG, "from SO: \n"+etWifiList);

       // List stored networks
       List<WifiConfiguration> configs = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
       for (WifiConfiguration config : configs) {
           textStatus+= "\n\n" + config.toString();
       }
       Log.v(TAG,"from marakana: \n"+textStatus);
     }
     return ssid;
   }
   ```

DISCLAIMER: while this is working code, not pseudo code, its only purpose is to illustrate the methods for data extraction from wifi connections and it should be adapted (and cleaned) before use.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D   1. marakana is marko gargenta, the author of many sample projects.  2. as i said, this is a mix and match, including the sample code you refer to.  :)

Comment: After detecting all wi-fi, how to connect with that wi-fi.

Comment: ask that as a separate question, please, @DennySharma.  :)

Comment: Don't forget the permissions: 
    
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Simple as 2 lines

```
WifiManager w=(WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
String wifi=w.getConnectionInfo().getSSID();
```

Remember to put this in your Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```