# Finding the information of routers in range of my mobile using android WiFi API

Tags: android, api, wifi, router

I want to create an android application which uses WiFi router information. Using android WiFi API, I am able to get all the information of all WiFi networks available but I want to find the information or unique identity of routers to which my mobile is in range of.

Is there any way to get this information ?

Comment: What kind of information are you looking for? IP addresses? Names?

Comment: Any unique identity of a wifi router from whose value change when i get into field of another wifi router.

Comment: So wer're talking about a wifi network made of different routers?

Comment: Yes, there are different routers which have same networks(one or many).

Comment: You could try checking the default gateway IP

Comment: What I have got till now is that each router has unique BSSID for each network. Now using that to make application.

Answer (score 1):

Network Info II

Shows info about the phone and the current network, Bluetooth, IPv6 and Cell connection.

```
**>> Information shown <<**
```

•Device IP and hostname, both private and public.

•Current mobile Cell and any neighbours, along with their signal strength, location info and type.

•IMSI/ IMEI.

•Information about the current mobile provider (MCC+MNC, current connection, etc.)

•The Android device unique ID.

•Full information regarding the WiFi connection (MAC, current SSID and BSSID, link speed, IP/Netmask, Gateway, DNS and DHCP servers, etc.)

Link is Bellow :
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=aws.apps.networkInfoIi

Answer (score 0):

this [snippet of working code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15976165/1166727) (which i cant repost because of anti spamming policy in SO) extracts everything from connected wifi, stored networks on device and available networks in "sight" of device.

when you say "unique identity", i imagine that you mean a wifi router's MAC address (which is called BSSID, "getMacAddress" being reserved for the DEVICE's mac address).