# Displaying current connected WIFI SSID name

Tags: java, android

I am displaying current connected WiFi SSID name in my android app..it displaying 
current connected WiFi SSID name.

problem is printing "rakesh" like this
Its printing along with this symbol" " can anyone help me

```
   ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   NetworkInfo wifiInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    if(wifiInfo.isConnected() == true){
        WifiInfo localInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        Details = "Connected to " + localInfo.getSSID();

    }else{
        Details = "Not Connected";
    }
```

Comment: check this for more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531940/how-to-get-name-of-wifi-network-out-of-android-using-android-api

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService (Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo ();
String ssid  = info.getSSID();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:
android.net.wifi.WifiInfo.getSSID

Answer (score 0):

**Try this.**

```
 WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getContext().getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
    String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
```

**Add Following Permission on your Manifest.**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late answer but from the documentation of [WifiInfo.getSSID()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getSSID()) :

> If the SSID can be decoded as UTF-8, it will be returned surrounded by double quotation marks

which seems to be the problem in your case. If you don't need the " characters just remove them from the String.