# How to fetch the connected Wifi name?

Tags: android

I have used the below code for fetching the Wifi name in android. Below is the code that i have used:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) mContext.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
       WifiInfo info;
       if (wifiManager != null && isWebViewLoaded) {
           info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
           String wifiName = info.getSSID();
}
```

The code works on other devices (below version 8), however I tried on Nexus 5X (Oreo v-8.1), it gives "Unknown SSID" against info.getSSID().

Comment: you can try something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391395/get-ssid-when-wifi-is-connected

Comment: I don't believe this is really a duplicate nor do those other solutions linked above and answered below address this. It appears to be an Android 8 or 8.1 issue. My Pixel 2 running 8.1 is giving me <unknown ssid>. However, this only happens when I target API 26, API 25 or lower seemed to work fine.

Comment: Alright, I figured this one out. It appears that in Android 8.1 (maybe 8.0 as well?) if you're targeting API 26+ getSSID() will always return <unknown ssid> UNLESS your app has the following permission: ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION. There is a bug logged for this behavior: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70795529 . I can't add an answer to this question because it was erroneously marked as a duplicate. It clearly is not.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think it's a bug though. They do the same for bluetooth scanning. It's a horrible way to do it and confuses the user, but it's meant as additional security

Comment: As @Glaucus said, from Android 8 you have to explicitly request those location  permissions via `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions`

Comment: @AlexAndro Event after requesting permission I am getting unknown ssid!

Comment: @GurleenSethi you also have to turn on GPS location thing. It seems that from 8.1+ it doesn't matter what SDK you target, you will still get unknown ssid unless you allow all those permissions plus GPS. i.e I'm targeting 25 but on Android P it shows unknown SSID

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326948/7676637)

```
public String getWifiName(Context context) {
   WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if (manager.isWifiEnabled()) {
       WifiInfo wifiInfo = manager.getConnectionInfo();
       if (wifiInfo != null) {
          DetailedState state = WifiInfo.getDetailedStateOf(wifiInfo.getSupplicantState());
          if (state == DetailedState.CONNECTED || state == DetailedState.OBTAINING_IPADDR) {
              return wifiInfo.getSSID();
          }
       }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This works on API < 26. This question is about API >= 26.