# How to get current wifi connection name in android pie(9) devices?

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-9.0-pie

I know it is very simple for you. Here I am just tried to get WiFi name in android pie devices. I am able to get WiFi name till Nogout devices with the help of below line of code.

```
 String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
```

I have tried lots of answer and Android developer docs but unfortunately, I can not get a WiFi name on my mobile(Nokia 6.1 plus). I Know I am doing mistakes.

I just want a code there I can get a wifi name from my mobile to my android studio logcat.

Comment: did you check this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531940/how-to-get-name-of-wifi-network-out-of-android-using-android-api

Comment: Did you achieved getting connected wifi name in android 9?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is related to permissions....since API level 27 you need either `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission. You may also need `CHANGE_WIFI_STATE` for Android 9 (that's the case for wifi scan anyway as per google [permisson model](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan)

then try this code

```
   ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) activity.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            wifiInfo.getSSID();
            String name = networkInfo.getExtraInfo();
            String ssid = "\"" + wifiInfo.getSSID() + "\"";
}
```

Comment: add your logcat

Comment: @MilanPansuriya Sorry dude. its not populating SSID for Andorid PIE

Comment: what is your device? I checked this code in Pie Device and Its work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get SSID value using

```
 WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) 
 context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
 wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
```

if it returns SSID as null, then turn on the location and try the same. 
Oreo 8.1+ devices require the coarse location runtime permission as well as location services to be turned on before retrieving the connected SSID.

Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#getconnectioninfo)

Comment: yes it returns a null value in my device and when i am on my location manually after that it returns a wifi name.